# Add Multiple Filters to SpringSecurity namespace FilterChain

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

How can I add multiple custom implementations of standard Http Filter to a Spring Security namespace FilterChainProxy? I know I can add one filter to the chain by using the after, before or position attributes. But how can I add more than one filter?. Here is my security config file

```
<http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/> 
<http pattern="/session_list.jsp" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/security/cas_logout.jsf" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/user/account_signup.jsf" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/user/company_user_association.jsf" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/user/account_signup_review.jsf" security="none"/>                       

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">            
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/security/cas_logout.jsf" invalidate-session="true"/>
    <custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter"/>
    <custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER"/>       
</http>

     <beans:bean id="portalSessionFilter" class="org.x.web.security.PortalSessionInterceptor"/>     
     <beans:bean id="requestUrlStackFilter" class="org.x.web.security.RequestUrlStackFilter"/>
```

I would like to add the **portalSessionFilter and requestUrlStackFilter** to the filter chain above. I can potentially do this

```
<custom-filter ref="portalSessionFilter" before="LAST"/>
```

But how do I add **requestUrlStackFilter** before LAST and right after **portalSessionFilter** BTW both of them are simple GenericFilterBean implementations.

I tried creating another **FilterChainProxy** bean with the above two filters in its chain list and add that bean as a custom-filter to the namespace configuration before LAST and the filters seem to work but my JSF navigation is broken, especially with commandLink (I think AJAX calls are failing when using this FilterChainProxy)

Can anyone suggest any ideas on how to add these two filters and possible other filters to the Spring Security Filter Chain?

Comment: As mentioned in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931812/how-to-use-more-than-one-custom-filter-invoked-after-each-other), I could position only max 3 like this: <custom-filter position="LAST" ref="filter3"/>
<custom-filter before="LAST" ref="filter2"/>
<custom-filter after="SWITCH_USER_FILTER" ref="filter1"/> since SwitchUserFilter being the last in the standard order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem I was having. I solved it by implementing my own filter chain instead of using the spring security filter chain proxy to chain my filters. The problem with FilterChainProxy is that it uses reset method at the end of the filter chain which will cause problems if you inject it in between the main spring security filter chain proxy.

The custom filter chain just processes the required filters and hands back control to the main spring security filterchainproxy. Here is how the config looks after the changes

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">           
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/security/cas_logout.jsf" invalidate-session="true"/>
    <custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter"/>
    <custom-filter ref="requestSingleLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="customFilterChain" before="LAST"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="customFilterChain" class="org.x.web.security.CustomFilterChain">
<beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:list>
        <filter-chain pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" filters="none"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/resources/**" filters="none"/>
        <filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="portalSessionFilter,requestUrlStackFilter"/>
    </beans:list>
</beans:constructor-arg>
```

Here **CustomFilterChain** extends **GenericFilterBean** but in the **doFilter** method chains the filters (matching the request pattern) and finally passes control back to the main spring security FilterChainProxy